# Why doesn't Swift force my designated initializer to call super?

Tags: swift, initialization, nsobject

This code is legal in Swift:

```
class Snapper : NSObject {
    var anim : UIDynamicAnimator
    init(referenceView:UIView) {
        self.anim = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView:referenceView)
        // super.init()
    }
}
```

Observe that in my initializer I didn't call `super.init()`; I commented out that line. But the Swift compiler doesn't complain. Why? I thought there was a rule that your designated initializer *must* call a designated initializer of its superclass. And I have a superclass, namely NSObject.

Is this a bug? Or is having NSObject as your superclass a special case? If so, why? I realize that NSObject has no instance variables that need initialization, but how do we know that its `init` doesn't do other things that need doing? Shouldn't Swift be giving a compile error here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an answer of the why but adding a symbolic breakpoint on `[NSObject init]` shows that it gets called even if `super.init()` is commented out.

It definitely seems a special case as replacing `NSObject` with any other class makes the compiler warn again about the missing super call. My guess is the the compiler handles this as a special case given that it's our base class with just one known designated initializer.

Comment: Very interesting. Good experiment, and this in fact _could_ be the right answer.

Comment: I can see from the symbolic breakpoint that you are right about what is happening behind the scenes. I've decided to accept this answer and file a bug report (21434444). Secret special cases are not the Swift Way. The rule "you must call super" should mean what it says. Thanks!

Comment: I submitted this as a bug report to Apple and they replied that this is intentional. It's not a special case with NSObject; you can see the same phenomenon with any superclass that has a plain and simple `init()`: if you don't call any `super.init(...)` method, `super.init()` is called for you. I regard this as wrong and have repeated my bug report, but I don't hold out much hope that Apple will agree with me.

Comment: Did you file an openradar so that I can submit the same report?

Comment: I told you my bug report number. Feel free to mention it in your report! (When I say "I repeated my bug report", I mean that they closed it and I replied, by adding a further note, that they should not.)

Comment: My bad... Mobile screen is just too small :)

Comment: You're not StackOverflowing while driving, are you? :)